# Regex to match a specific string and no more than two slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry, I could not think of a better title to describe it.  I have a list of URLs and a set of regex patterns to compare to those URLs.  One pattern is a bit too greedy, and I'd like to constrain it so that it doesn't match when the url has more than two slashes.  For example:

Current RegExp: `/something/*`

- Matches on: `/something/1234`
- Matches on: `/something/something`
- Matches on: `/something/to/much`

How can I revise the regex so that it only,

- Matches on: `/something/1234`
- Matches on: `/something/something`
- **And not on**: `/something/to/much`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qD5zI8/1)

```
 ^\/something\/[^\/]*$
```

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `\/`: Match backslash, need to escape
3. **`[^\/]*`: Match anything that is not backslash, zero or more times**
4. `$`: End of line